# unreadable output with var_dump on xampp windows

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I'm having some issue with var_dump.i'm using xampp 1.7.3 on windows.

I think in previous version i could output a variable with var_dump without `print "<pre>" print "</pre>"` `firebug` is not `installed on my firefox` and i'm not using `xdebug`.

Formally i have even red colored and nicely formatted output.Now it's completly unreadable.Can anyonw give me a tips n how to correct that.And html_errors is on from what i saw in php_info.thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were using Xdebug before; you're not using it now. Without it, there are no colors, and there are no HTML line breaks (use `nl2br`, change the Content-type header to `text/plain` or put the output in a `<pre>` block).

See the ["Variable Display Features" on the manual of Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/display).

Comment: yeah now i remember i think i was doing javascript debugging from netbeans and had to use xdebug.ok thanks bruv.What are risk when i'll want to use PDT or Zend studio? thanks for the reply!!

Answer (score 5):

Un-comment this line in you php.ini file.

zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

Comment: Excellent answer ++++

Answer (score 2):

This topic helped me at the time I was working in PHP5. With a fresh install of Xampp (**PHP 7+**), xdebug is no longer installed. It must be done manually. Below the explanations :

1. Goto https://xdebug.org/wizard.php
2. Make a `phpinfo();` on your project and paste it in the textarea on [the xdebug website](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php)
3. It returns some informations on your system like `Xdebug installed: no`
4. Follow the instructions in the bottom of the results page
5. After the manipulation, if you check again your `phpinfo();`

   This time we get `Xdebug installed: 2.6.0`. xdebug works !

Comment: The new Xdebug interface is less explicit than before. You must obviously add the absolute path pointing to the dll for it to work !